# Is it permissible to pray while leaning on the wall?

Tags: salat, sunnah

When someone want to pray all night, his back hurts because of how long he stood. Is he allowed to pray leaning on the wall or would that go against the Sunnah of the Prophet (alaihi As-Salat wa As-Salam)?

Comment: [How am i supposed to pray when I'm having terrible headchaes?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-am-i-supposed-to-pray-when-im-having-terrible-headaches) is relevant and might also be covering this.

Answer (score 1):

**It is permitted** if you are sick and that your sickness would worsen if you prayed while standing or that the recovery of it would get delayed.

The prophet (SAW) [said about praying](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/67934/when-is-it-permissible-for-a-person-to-pray-sitting-in-obligatory-prayers) (*it is narrated by al-Bukhaari (1050) from ‘Imraan ibn Husayn*):

> Pray standing; if you cannot, then sitting; and if you cannot, then lying on your side.

As for your case, you want to do what is called Qiyaam Al-Layl (praying at night as Sunnah) which **is permissible**, according to the scholars, to pray standing or sitting with **no excuse**, or to do both. So a person may pray and recite sitting down, and just before doing Rukoo’ he may stand up and recite the rest of the aayahs standing up, then do Rukoo’ and Sujood, then he can do likewise in the second Rak’ah.

It is worth mentioning that if it was permissible to **sit** for such situations in praying, then it is definitely okay to do it while **leaning on a wall** which is nearly like standing.

[Source](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13340/description-of-the-prophets-prayer)

Comment: You misunderstood, I didn't mean to pray sitting, but to pray standing while leaning on the wall because my back would hurt less if I lean

Comment: Yes, I understood you well. But that is how the Hadith was stated. I can't change its words just to fit an X case. But I also wrote what has been ruled about your situation, it starts at "As for your case..." till the end of the answer.

Comment: I have explained it further. I hope it is now clear.