# Praying sitting down

Tags: salat, fiqh, practical-islam

Salam alykum,
I am an over the road truck driver which means I’m inside my truck 4 to 5 days a week. My question is can I pray sitting down inside my truck? My truck has a low roof and I can’t stand up inside it, I have tried praying outside somewhere around my truck but unfortunately I’ll keep on getting distracted with “ will someone attack or try to do something to me from the back while I’m praying? Or would someone crash into my truck while I’m praying around it and I end up getting injured?” So lately I have been praying SITTING DOWN inside my truck since I can not stand up. Am I doing the right thing? If not what should I do?
Jazak allah Khair

Comment: Maybe the question content of [How am I supposed to pray when I'm having terrible headaches](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-am-i-supposed-to-pray-when-im-having-terrible-headaches) already answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

### In the name of Allah, the most Gracious, Most Merciful

**All praise and thanks are due to God, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in God from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever God guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but God, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**Your question:** can I pray sitting down inside my truck?

**Answer:** Standing, bowing and prostrating are pillars or essential parts of the prayer. Whoever can do them, it is obligatory for him to do them in the manner prescribed in sharee’ah. Whoever is not able to do them because of sickness or old age, it is Sunnah for him to sit on the ground or on a chair. Firstly, you need to have a valid excuse for you to pray while sitting. If not, then it's haram for you pray inside the truck.

Allah Says:

> "Maintain with care the [obligatory] prayers and [in particular] the middle prayer and stand before Allah, devoutly obedient." [**[The Cow, 2:238]**](https://quran.com/2/238)

(who had piles) I asked Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) about the praying of a man while sitting. He said, **"If he prays while standing it is better and he who prays while sitting gets half the reward of that who prays standing; and whoever prays while Lying gets half the reward of that who prays while sitting."** [**[Narrated by Imran bin Husain]**](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/18/35)

the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

**“Pray standing.”** And because standing is one of the pillars (essential parts of prayer) for the one who is able to do it, so he must do it, like the recitation. Being unable to do other things does not mean that this is waived, as is also the case if he is unable to recite.

Standing during an obligatory prayer is one of the pillars or essential parts of the prayer, and it not permissible to omit it unless one is unable to stand because of sickness or intense fear, and the like. If a person omits it deliberately then his prayer is invalid. Hence it is clear to you that what you are doing by performing your prayers whilst sitting down is not permissible because you have no sharia excuse, and your prayer sitting down is regarded as invalid.

Which means that your prayer is invalid. First, you should park your truck somewhere where cars don't have chance to hit you and pray while standing beside your truck.

---

**Sources:**

1. [**Rulings and issues about praying on a chair**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/50684/rulings-and-issues-about-praying-on-a-chair)
2. [**Praying sitting down with no excuse**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/13822/praying-sitting-down-with-no-excuse)