# Praying at work

Tags: salat, work

I work in McDonalds and the only suitable place I can think of is the seating area. The tables and chairs are basically booths, I'll have to get out to stand up. My question is can I pray whilst seated and with my shoes on? I've read in a few sites that it's permissible to pray with shoes on as long as they don't have impurities on them. I'm not exactly sure what it means by impurities, does it mean by dirt in general? Time to time stuff like drinks and liquids drops on my shoes.

Comment: Could you go outdoors to pray? Praying sitting gets you only half the reward, and i think you're only supposed to if you are truly unable to stand. But if you stand when working (do you?) then you don't really have an excuse.

Comment: There's no place outside to pray, I am able to stand and move around but as I said the only suitable place is the sitting area. Given my situation, would it be better to pray at work if able to or should I wait until I can go home?

Comment: Not even in the car park? Try ask your boss if he can set aside a place for you? Definitely don't wait. That's being sinful.

Comment: There's no other place but the dining area. Car park is in constant use

Comment: Praying while sitting - in fard prayers - is not permitted unless you have a valid reason: Praying normally or in a different way would be harmful for you for example, see also [How am I supposed to pray when I'm having terrible headaches](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-am-i-supposed-to-pray-when-im-having-terrible-headaches). Taharah (purity) and najassah (impurity) are no synonyms of cleanness and dirtiness.